# ReactJS Route different layout

Tags: reactjs

./index.js

```
import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import App from './App';    

    ReactDOM.render(
          <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>,
          rootElement);
```

./App.js

```
import { Route } from 'react-router';
    return (
        <div>
            <Layout>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Auth} />
            </Layout>
            <Home>
              <Route path='/home' component={Sample} />
              <Route path='/test' component={Sample1} />
             </Home>
        </div>
    )
```

Layout.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Layout extends Component {
    displayName = Layout.name
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Home.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Col, Grid, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Top from '../components/menu/Top';

export class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Top />
                <Grid fluid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={12}>
                            {this.props.children}
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to use different layout for different component, i try, but it did not work out, what am I doing wrong? Worst part is there is so many different sample, and none is working
updated with image, the different is 1 with top bar and 1 without, the login page should not appear the topbar, and the other 2 that in the home should had share the top, but i can't find any working sample for it
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s hard to see from the code above or seeing the URL that you are using to generate the screenshot.

I’d suggest moving Home and Layout inside your Route components and compose your UI. Currently the components will render even if their children do not.

Try moving your Home inside Sample and Sample1 and Layout inside of Auth.

Comment: are u saying that is not possible to use different layout or share layout? just like a master page?

Comment: No, it is possible to share layouts. Think of 'Route' as an if statement that wraps your UI. If you were to remove all the Route components from your example above you'd still have two layouts rendered.

Comment: u mean the content of the layout and home to move into each component? izzit it will be repeated design across multiple component? any chance to work like a masterpage where it just contain the layout, just need to change the 1 layout, it will affect all the component that using the layout?

Comment: No just wrap the contents of Auth with Layout. So import the Layout component inside of the Auth, and import Home inside of Sample and Sample1.

Comment: Ok, is working, thanks for the great idea, i manage to make it work, although not as what I expect like what known as masterpage

Comment: Great! Yeah I see what you mean but this is actually a big benefit of using a virtual DOM library like React; you can compose the UI based on the data, in your case, the URL. This allows you focus on a top down approach to the UI. This may help https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html